# Excel- how to convert semicolon delimited csv file containing newlines into columns?

Tags: excel, csv

I have seen several questions before on this topic, but none of then have been able to give me a solution.

I am using Excel 2013. I need to convert a semicolon delimited file into excel. however, the problem is that some column contain new lines, and excel is interpreting those values as a new row. This is the sample data that I have:

```
Id;Name;Access Code;Description
1;xyz;001;"This is an
example of a new
line column"
2;bhc;002; Normal output
```

The format of the file is ANCI. Any suggestions or help will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try Text to Columns?

Comment: Yes I tried and it still doesn't work

Comment: I had no trouble opening the example in OpenOffice Calc (the GNU equivalent of Excel). When I opened the file I just specified that it was semicolon deliminated and it opened fine. Maybe you can provide a link to the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a column value that contains new line sequence, surround it by double quotes (as you did).

However, excel has a problem with implementation semi-colon as separator mixed with values that contains new line characters. In that case new line within a value will be treated as new record.

However, if you change the separator to a comma, every thing works fine.

So try:

Id,Name,Access Code,Description
1,xyz,001,"This is an
example of a new
line column"
2,bhc;002, Normal output